# How to create 2 graph, for male and female on Python

Tags: matplotlib

this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("titanic.csv")

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot (df(x="Age", y="Sex", color='purple'))
plt.ylabel('Male')
plt.xlabel('Age Group')
plt.title('Male that went Aboard')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(df(x='Age', y='Sex',color='green'))
plt.ylabel('Female')
plt.xlabel('Age Group')
plt.title('Female that went Aboard')
plt.show()
```

I want to view Male and Female on 2 different graph under "Sex"
But receive an error: 
Thanks

Comment: what error? what kind of graph are you trying to make?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/home/vermap/test.csv")
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(list(df[df['Sex'].isin(["Male"])]['Age']), "-o", color='purple')
plt.xlabel('Age Group')
plt.title('Male that went Aboard')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(list(df[df['Sex'].isin(["Female"])]['Age']), "-o", color='green')
plt.xlabel('Age Group')
plt.title('Female that went Aboard')
plt.show()
```

Let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 0):

The code below resolved my question.

Thanks for responding!

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_csv("titanic.csv")
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Sex'])
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.hist(df[df['Sex'].isin["Male"]]['Age'], "-o", color='purple')
plt.xlabel('Age Group')
plt.title('Male that went Aboard')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.hist(df[df['Sex'].isin["Female"]]['Age'], "-o", color='green')
plt.xlabel('Age Group')
plt.title('Female that went Aboard')
plt.show()
```